# git-svn anonymous checkout fails with -s

Tags: authentication, https, git-svn, anonymous

I'm trying to use git to clone an svn repository with std layout (using the `-s` option). The repository uses `https` anonymously (the repository is at https://secure.simplistix.com/svn/xlwt/). I can check the repository out fine using `svn`, but with `git-svn` I get password prompts and then cannot check out (I don't have an account for this repository):

```
Authentication realm:  Simplistix Subversion Server
Password for 'davidf': 
Authentication realm:  Simplistix Subversion Server
Username: 
Password for '': 
Authentication realm:  Simplistix Subversion Server
Username: 
Password for '': 
W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem has no item: '/svn/!svn/bc/100/xlwt' path not found
W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is just searching aggressively for old history.
This may take a while on large repositories
```

The resulting repository is entirely empty

`git-svn` seems to assume that if the repository starts with `https`, authentication is required. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: I know this is old, but to help others please mention in your question and title that you’re using the `-s` option, since that is probably key to the issue you were seeing.

Comment: Good point. I've added that info. Anyone testing - I can't currently use `git svn` or `svn` on the above URL - I get a `OPTIONS` error with `200 OK`

Comment: As a followup to this, it's worth pointing out that xlwt development has now moved to github: https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt ...so, no need for gitsvn anymore! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an idea what this might be related to:

http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3242

If it's not that, then you're likely out of luck...
The root of my repository is *not* publicly accessible...

Comment: It does indeed look like that - git-svn clone can check the whole thing out, but add the -s to get branch support and it fails... however downgrading to subversion 1.4 doesn't fix it, so it seems that this is actually a similar bug in git-svn itself

Comment: hgsubversion rescues this as it doesn't access this in the same way, so that's a workaround...

Comment: Yeah, the problem is on the server, not on the client.

Comment: @DavidFraser is hgsvn more powerful than git-svn?

Comment: @hugemeow - I haven't used hgsvn much (I think only when I was testing the above) so don't have much to comment on. I think these issues have been addressed in the svn server (see the issue linked above) although the above repository isn't there any more so I can't test exactly.

Answer (score 6):

The reason is probably that the root of the SVN repository is not accessible to anonymous users.

From `git help svn`:

> When tracking multiple directories (using `--stdlayout`, `--branches`, or `--tags` options), git svn will attempt to connect to the root (or highest allowed level) of the Subversion repository. This default allows better tracking of history if entire projects are moved within a repository, but may cause issues on repositories where read access restrictions are in place.

Since you’re using the `-s` option (shorthand for `--stdlayout`), this will affect you.

To prevent git svn from attempting to connect to the root of the repository, add the option `--no-minimize-url` to the command line.

See also: [git help svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn)

Comment: so do you mean git svn will always fail if anonymous use cannot visit svn root?

Comment: @hugemeow it will fail if anonymous users cannot visit the root, **and** you use `--stdlayout`, or `--branches`, or `--tags`, or their equivalent short options, **and** you don’t specify `--no-minimize-url`.