# Work-around for failing "git svn clone" (requiring full history)

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I want to convert a Subversion repository sub-directory (denoted by `module` here) into a git repository with full history. There are many `svn copy` operations (Subversion people call them branches) in the history of my Subversion repository. The release policy has been that after each release or other branches created, the old URL is left unused and the new URL replaces the old one for containing the work.

Optimally, by my reading, it seems like this should do the trick:

```
$ git svn clone --username=mysvnusername --authors-file=authors.txt \
    --follow-parent \
    http://svnserver/svn/src/branches/x/y/apps/module module
```

(where `branches/x/y/` depicts the newest branch). But I got an error, which looks something like this:

```
W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem has no item: '/svn/src/!svn/bc/100/branches/x/y/apps/module' path not found
W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is just searching aggressively for old history.
```

(**Update:** Adding option `--no-minimize-url` to the above does not remove the error message.)

The directory `module` get created and populated, but the Subversion history past the newest `svn copy` commit is not imported (the git repository created ends up having just two commits when I expected hundreds).

The question is, how to export the full Subversion history in the presence of this situation?

### Possible Cause

1. Searching for the error message, I found this: [git-svn anonymous checkout fails with -s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493052/git-svn-anonymous-checkout-fails-with-s)
   which linked to this Subversion issue: http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3242

   What I understand by my reading, something in Subversion 1.5 changed about how the client accesses the repository. With newer Subversion, if there is no read access to some super directory of the URL path (true for me, `svn ls http://svnserver/svn` fails with `403 Forbidden`), then we fail with some Subversion operations.
2. Jeff Fairley in his answer points out that spaces in the Subversion URL might also cause this error message (confirmed by user Owen). Have a look at his solution to see how he solved the case if your `git svn clone` is failing for the same resson.
3. Dejay Clayton in his answer reveals that if the deepest subdirectory components in branch and tag svn urls are equally named (e.g. `.../tags/release/1.0.0` and `.../branches/release-candidates/1.0.0`) then this error could occur.

Comment: I can't speak for the functionality, but I can [for the warning.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12065104/877115) You can ignore the "Ignoring error" bit. It is unrelated to that subversion.tigris.org issue you linked. If anything, based on reading the git-svn source, it should throw a supplemental error for the tigris case.

Comment: It seems to me the warning is related to the fact that past the most recent `svn copy` I will not get the history imported. The `svn copy` (URL change or creation of new branch) gets imported as adding all the files so far created. Hence my git repository contains only two commits when I expect hundreds.

Comment: Is this a public repository? I swore I read a question recently where an apache project was rejecting `git svn` clones with the `!svn` path syntax simply because the project administrators didn't want `git-svn` taking up their repo bandwidth for half a day. For the life of me I can't find the question. This was a public Apache foundation project, mind you.

Comment: No, this is evil company private repository! :-) I do not have read access to do `svn ls http://svnserver/svn` - all the other directories okay. There is no deliberate blocking of `git svn`. (As to the Open Source repository, it seems it would have worked better and had been better service to just organize the mirroring by the maintainers... ;-)

Comment: I suspect you're right about the read access issue; I just mean to suggest the error is wrong (at the very least, if it's being thrown for your use-case it should be more clear about the cause of the problem). You might try the git list for this.

Comment: Yup, and we should note that I have no problem doing `svn log -v http://svnserver/svn/src/branches/x/y/apps/module` and seeing the history past the `svn copy` barrier. There should be a work-around possible for `git svn` if the read access permissions are the issue here like it seems to me.

Comment: I think if your update is a solution, you should have posted it as an answer separately, so this question could be marked as solved.

Comment: @Alaksey - I think you are right. For lack of better ways of doing this, I moved my distasteful solution from the question to an independent answer, and accepted as the solution (while waiting for better way of doing this).

Comment: See my answer below for how this problem can also occur if you have identically-named subdirectories within tags or branches.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ran into this problem when I had identically-named subdirectories within branches or tags.

For example, I had tags `candidates/1.0.0` and `releases/1.0.0`, and this caused the documented error because subdirectory `1.0.0` appears within both `candidates` and `releases`.

Per [git-svn docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn):

> When using multiple --branches or --tags, git svn does not automatically handle name collisions (for example, if two branches from different paths have the same name, or if a branch and a tag have the same name). In these cases, use init to set up your Git repository then, before your first fetch, edit the $GIT_DIR/config file so that the branches and tags are associated with different name spaces.

So while the following command failed due to similarly named `candidates` and `releases` tags:

```
git svn clone --authors-file=../authors.txt --no-metadata \
    --trunk=/trunk --branches=/branches --tags=/candidates \
    --tags=/releases --tags=/tags -r 100:HEAD \
    --prefix=origin/ \
    svn://example.com:3692/my-repos/path/to/project/
```

the following sequence of commands did work:

```
git svn init --no-metadata \
    --trunk=/trunk --branches=/branches --tags=/tags \
    --prefix=origin/ \
    'svn://example.com:3692/my-repos/path/to/project/'

git config --add svn-remote.svn.tags \
    'path/to/project/candidates/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/Candidates/*'

git config --add svn-remote.svn.tags \
    'path/to/project/releases/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/Releases/*'

git svn fetch --authors-file=../authors.txt -r100:HEAD
```

Note that this only worked because there were no other conflicts within `branches` and `tags`.  If there were, I would have had to resolve them similarly.

After successfully cloning the SVN repository, I then executed the following steps in order to: turn SVN tags into GIT tags; turn `trunk` into `master`; turn other references into branches; and relocate remote paths:

```
# Make tags into true tags
cp -Rf .git/refs/remotes/origin/tags/* .git/refs/tags/
rm -Rf .git/refs/remotes/origin/tags

# Make other references into branches
cp -Rf .git/refs/remotes/origin/* .git/refs/heads/
rm -Rf .git/refs/remotes/origin
cp -Rf .git/refs/remotes/* .git/refs/heads/ # May be missing; that's okay
rm -Rf .git/refs/remotes

# Change 'trunk' to 'master'
git checkout trunk
git branch -d master
git branch -m trunk master
```

Answer (score 8):

Not a full answer, but perhaps the snippet you are missing (I am interested in migrating as well, so I have found that part of the puzzle).

When you look at the [documentation of git-svn](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html), you will find the following option:

```
--no-minimize-url
```

> When tracking multiple directories (using --stdlayout, --branches, or --tags options), git svn will attempt to connect to the root (or highest allowed level) of the Subversion repository. This default allows better tracking of history if entire projects are moved within a repository, but may cause issues on repositories where read access restrictions are in place. Passing --no-minimize-url will allow git svn to accept URLs as-is without attempting to connect to a higher level directory. This option is off by default when only one URL/branch is tracked (it would do little good).

This fits to the situation you have, so that `git svn` does not try to read a higher level of the directory tree (which will be blocked).

At least you could give it a try ...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I just tried to add this option to the `git svn clone --follow-parent` command, but it did not have noticeable effect (it seems like not to apply to *that* scenario – I am not able to use the `--stdlayout`, `--branches`, or `--tags` options due to way the repository is structured).

Answer (score 3):

I recently migrated a long list of SVN repositories into Git and towards the end ran into this problem. Our SVN structure was pretty sloppy, so I had to use `--no-minimize-url` quite a bit. Typically, I'd run a command like:

```
$ git svn clone http://[url]/svn/[repo]/[path-to-code] \
            -s --no-minimize-url \
            -A authors.txt
```

The last few migrations I ran had a space in the URL. I don't know if it was the space or something else, but I was getting the same error you were seeing. I didn't want to get into modifying config files if I didn't have to, and luckily I ended up finding a solution. I ended up skipping the `-s --no-minimize-url` options in favor of explicitly declaring the paths differently.

```
$ git svn clone http://[url]/svn/[repo]/ \
            --trunk="/[path-to-code]/trunk" \
            --branches="/[path-to-code]/branches" \
            --tags="/[path-to-code]/tags" \
            -A authors.txt \
            --follow-parent
```

- Note that I added `--follow-parent` from your example, but I'm also not sure that it made any difference.
- Remember that these repos had spaces in them, hence the `""` around the trunk/branches/tags paths.

Comment: Whether you had a similar case to mine and other error reports could be tested by simple `svn ls http://[url]/svn` (is it giving `403` or succeeding). I personally have a sense that spaces should not matter -- it is after all much easier to write whitespace-tolerantly correct perl code than shell scripts... :-)

Comment: I do not have the original setting available to test if your solution works or not. Looks really promising -- I somehow missed the possibility of providing relative paths for `--trunk`, `--tags`, and `--branches`. It would be interesting to see your `[remote-svn]` sections if they look similar to what I got after my `sed` foo. If I have possibility to test this, or if somebody confirms that the advice of using relative paths for trunk, tags, branches solved the permission issue, I will mark this answer the chosen answer. Thanks!!!

Comment: Here's my `.git/config` from that conversion. I don't have a `[remote-svn]` but I have a `[svn-remote]`.

https://gist.github.com/jfairley/416393762c4642e20992

Answer (score 2):

[*I realize this should be a comment on Jeff Fairley's answer but I don't have the reputation to post it as such.  Since the original poster did ask for confirmation the approach worked I'm providing it as an answer.*]

I can confirm that his solution works for the problem he (and I) ran into caused by spaces in the path.  I had the same requirements (clone a single module from an SVN repo with history) except that I had no branches or tags to worry about whatsoever.

I tried several permutations of providing the full path to the module in the URL (e.g. using `--no-minimise-url`, specifying `--trunk` or `--stdlayout`) with no success.  For me the result was usually a git repo with a full history log but no files whatsoever.  This may or may not be the same problem FooF encountered (no read access in SVN) but it was certainly caused by having a space in the path to my module.

Trying again with only the SVN repo base as the URL and the path to my module in `--trunk` worked flawlessly.  Afterwards my .git/config looks like this:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = false
        loggallrefupdates = true
        symlinks = false
        ignorecase = true
        hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[svn-remote "svn"]
        url = https://[url]/svn/[repo]
        fetch = trunk/[path-to-code]:refs/remotes/trunk
[svn]
        authorsfile = ~/working/authors-transform.txt
```

and subsequent `git` and `git svn` commands are throwing no errors at all.  Thanks Jeff!

Answer (score 1):

*[This is the original poster <strike>speaking</strike> writing. The below used to be update to the question, but as it solved the case - albeit unsatisfactorily to my taste - I will post it as an answer lacking a better solution.]*

I do not like this, but I ended up doing `clone`  splitted into `init` and `fetch` with some editing of `.git/config` between (`repopath=apps/module`, `gitreponame=module`):

```
$ git svn init--username=mysvnusername \
            --branches=/src/branches/ \
            --trunk=/src/trunk/${repopath} \
            --tags=/src/tags/ \
            http://svnserver/svn/src ${gitreponame}
$ cd ${gitreponame}
$ sed -i.bak "s|*:|*/${repopath}:|" .git/config
$ git svn fetch --authors-file=../authors.txt --follow-parent
```

I could not find how to specify the branches for subdirectory migration with `git svn` - hence the editing of the `.git/config` file. The following unified diff illustrates the effect of the editing with `sed`:

```
 [svn-remote "svn"]
        url = http://svnserver/svn/src
        fetch = trunk/apps/module:refs/remotes/trunk
-       branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/*
-       tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
+       branches = branches/*/apps/module:refs/remotes/*
+       tags = tags/*/apps/module:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

As the actual desired `HEAD` was in an another URL, I ended just adding another `[svn-remote]` section to `.git/config`:

```
+ [svn-remote "svn-newest"]
+       url = http://svnserver/svn/src
+       fetch = branches/x/y/apps/module:refs/remotes/trunk
+       branches = branches/*/apps/module:refs/remotes/*
+       tags = tags/*/apps/module:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

(in real life experiment I also added here some branches that were not picked up by the first fetch), and fetching again:

```
$ git svn fetch --authors-file=../authors.txt --follow-parent svn-newest
```

This way I ended having the full Subversion history migrated to the newly generated git repository.

**Note-1** : I probably could have just told my "trunk" to be `branches/x/y/apps/module` as the meaning of "trunk" for `git-svn` seems to basically have the meaning of git `HEAD` (Subversion concepts of trunk, branches, tags have no deep technical basis, they are matter of socially agreed convention).

**Note-2** : probably `--follow-parent` is not required for `git svn fetch`, but I have no way of knowing or experimenting now.

**Note-3** : While earlier reading of [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git) which seems to be a wrapper over `git-svn` I failed to see the motivation, but seeing the messy presentation of tags I kind of get it now. I would try `svn2git` next time if I had to try doing this again.

**P.S.** This is rather awkward way of doing the operation. Secondary problem here (why the editing of the `.git/config` by external was required) seems to be that

1. Subversion branches do not have any essential technical meaning (*branches* and *tags* in Subversion are just a *socially agreed labels* for a versioned file system copy together with "standard" or otherwise socially agreed convention where the copies are done - *trunk* also has no technical meaning), and
2. `git svn` implementation strictly assumes the social Subversion conventions to be followed to a degree (which is not possible if you just want to migrate a subdirectory and not the whole Subversion repository).

**TODO:** It would be helpful to have the format of the `.git/config` file explained here as it relates to `git svn` - for example I have now (after one and half year of writing the original answer) no idea what the `[svn-remote "svn-newest"]` means above. Also the approach could be automated by writing a script, but this is beyond my current interest in the problem and I do not have access to the original Subversion repository or replication of the issue.

Comment: See my answer below for a way around dealing with .git/config.